# (TBS) TinyButStrong How to use Multiple 'when' for a block ? Example when [hasHouse] = 1 and [name] = 'bob'

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

So I have a block and I want to use the 'when' condition, I tried using but got no results.
If I just leave one of the conditions i get back results, but I dont get back anything if I use both, and would it be possible to add more conditions ?

```
[table;block=begin; when [table.hasHouse] =  1, [table.name] = ‘bob’]
[table.hasHouse]
[table.name]
[table.address]
[table;block=end]
```

Answer (score 0):

TBS conditional expressions can only be simple. This is because the Template Engine has to leave this kind of difficulty to the programing language.

So they are workarounds, see FAQ [How to make a condition for parameter if/when using operators like AND, OR ?](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/support.php#faq_or)